# DB2 error: SQL subselect error not recognized

Tags: sql, db2

I think I just found an error in DB2 itself. When I run this code I expect it to throw an error when executing the delete statement (the subselect wrongly uses A_NAME instead of NAME). But: it acts as if there was no where clause and deletes all the rows in table NAMES!

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES    (A_NAME VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE OLDNAMES (NAME   VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES ('ANNA'), ('ELLA'), ('JOHN'), ('EARL');
INSERT INTO OLDNAMES VALUES ('ELLA'), ('EARL');

-- this should throw an error message:
DELETE FROM NAMES WHERE A_NAME IN (SELECT A_NAME FROM OLDNAMES);

-- this should show ANNA & JOHN if the subselect 
-- was correct, but shows nothing
SELECT * FROM NAMES;

-- cleanup
DROP TABLE NAMES;
DROP TABLE OLDNAMES;
```

I ran it on a DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.9

Or is "not a bug, but a feature"?!

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong.  SQL has scoping rules for resolving column references in subqueries.  If the column reference is not resolved in the inner query, then it looks to the outer query.

These are the rules of SQL, not specific to DB2.

That is SQL interprets your logic as:

```
DELETE FROM NAMES
    WHERE NAMES.A_NAME IN (SELECT NAMES.A_NAME FROM OLDNAMES ON);
```

And this is valid -- if meaningless -- SQL.

This is why qualifying ALL column references is recommended.  The better way to write this query is:

```
DELETE FROM NAMES
    WHERE NAMES.A_NAME IN (SELECT ON.A_NAME FROM OLDNAMES ON);
```

Comment: Wow! So the inner select produces all 4 names from NAMES, right?

Comment: No. It must work as follows logically. A check is performed for each qualified row in `NAMES`. For each such a row a result set is formed in the sub-select. Every time it consists of 2 rows with the same constant got from `A_NAME` column of the row being evaluated for deletion. The result of such an evaluation for every row in `NAMES` is obviously TRUE (`valX in (valX, valX)` is TRUE for every `valX`) and it’s is why you get all the rows deleted. The query works correctly.